# Google Play can't sell apps

Tags: android, google-play, payment-processing, android-pay

I have created game using Unity game engine. It works perfectly fine. I want to upload it to Google Play, I am new to Google Play Developer Console and to this whole Google Play thing actually. I managed to upload .apk and filled all the necessary info. Now it is in beta test. The game will be pai. And that's where my problem is. When I(or other testers) try to buy the game, error pops up. If I try to buy the game via PC or phone, error is this:

```
An error occurred while getting the status of your purchase.
```

As far as I understand it's caused by my Google Wallet. I've filled my payment settings in Google Wallet and payment method(wire transfer(I'm from Ukraine)) in Google Wallet Merchant, my buisness address and address. I searched all over the net to find similar problems and solutions to the them, but couldn't find. Please help.

Oh and recently I've found out that there is also a Google Wallet Merchant for Digital Goods. Do I need it to sell apps? Because it's not supported in Ukraine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have entered faulty info. Otherwise try contacting help services, I'm sure they have already encountered similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache/data on your Play Store App (Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Store) or the cache/cookies on your browser.  Else, you can check out the [Google Wallet Help Center](https://support.google.com/wallet/?hl=en#topic=3209985) for more troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google payment ---> you will have multiple payment mode updated and your primary card or payment might be blocked or expired, change this to new added payment card or mode